# Lombok @RequiredArgsConstructor in multi-module project is not preserved

Tags: java, annotations, lombok

Is @RequiredArgsConstructor preserved accross modules?

I have a very simple project structure (2 maven modules):

- dependency-A
- sprint-boot-app

In **dependency-A** I declare following class:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RestController
@Validated
@Slf4j
public abstract class ControllerBase {}
```

Now in **spring-boot-app**:

```
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
public class ConcreteController extends ControllerBase {

    private final SomeDependency dependency
```

After this IntelliJ says that

> Variable dependency might not been initialized

If I check decompiled version of *ControllerBase* from ***sprint-boot-app*** module:

```
@RestController
@Validated
public class ControllerBase {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyController.class);

    public ControllerBase () {
    }
}
```

Is it restriction of Lombok or I should configure maven-compiler plugin somehow, so @RequiredArgsConstructor will be preserved? Please advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lombok annotations cannot be inherited.
They are compile time directives that add code to the annotated class and only the annotated class.
Even if you were creating a child class in the same module it would not propagate.

You will have to annotate each class with `@RequiredArgsConstructor`.

Comment: thanks, is it possible to disable transformation of those annotations in one module? So they will do nothing in dependency-A module?

Comment: You can disable lombok entirely for any given directory and all source files that exist in that directory or any subdirectory thereof (see the documentation on the lombok.config file), but I have no idea why you'd want to disable lombok annotations like this for a given directory. Why are you adding them if you don't want them processed? @tillias

Comment: @rzwitserloot I want them to be processed in spring-boot-app module, but not in dependency-A. Can you point me out please how to disable it for dir?

Comment: Lombok Annotations will never be passed to child classes. **They are not inherited**.
If you don't want the Lombok annotations to be used then **do not** include them.
You have to add the Lombok annotations to **every class** that you want it to work on.

Answer (score 1):

copy past from [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/features/constructor)

`@RequiredArgsConstructor` generates a constructor with one parameter for each field that requires special handling. All non-initialized final fields get a parameter, as well as any fields that are marked as `@NonNull` that aren't initialized where they are declared. For those fields marked with `@NonNull`, an explicit null check is also generated. The constructor will throw a NullPointerException if any of the parameters intended for the fields marked with `@NonNull` contain null. The order of the parameters match the order in which the fields appear in your class.

Comment: How this answers my original question? Thanks anyways

Comment: can u upload ur build.gradle file ?

Comment: Well it seems I have to somehow disable processing in dependency-A module.